# How can I show the title in front of logo not under it in Shiny R

Tags: html, css, r, position, shiny

So the following code writes the title under logo while I want it to be in front of the logo. In titlePanel help in RStudio there's no help regarding positioning the title. Any hack for this?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  list(tags$head(HTML('<img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/oddharmonic/554743/66688/66688_600.gif" border="0" style="border:2px width="10"  height="10"   alt="Photo of Milford Sound in New Zealand!" />'))),
  div(style="padding: 0px 0px",
      titlePanel(
        title="University of Wisconsin-Madison Database Group", windowTitle="FML"
      )
  ),
```

This is how it looks like now:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I can think of. You can wrap your `<img />` tag inside a `<h1>...</h1>` as follows:

```
server <- function(input,output,session){  
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    list(tags$head(HTML('<h1> <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/oddharmonic/554743/66688/66688_600.gif" border="0" style="border:2px width="10"  height="10"   alt="Photo of Milford Sound in New Zealand!"/> University of Wisconsin-Madison Database Group</h1>')))
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```